# How to POST in AWS cloud logic for Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

As I m using AWS Mobile hub for Cloud Logic integration.

How would i send data to the lambda function?

Code:

```
public void postCloudLogic(String mName,String mClass) {
    // Create components of api request
    final String method = "POST";

    final String path = "/test_rds_lambda/?name="+mName+"&class="+mClass;

    final String body = "";
    final byte[] content = body.getBytes(StringUtils.UTF8);

    final Map parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("lang", "en_US");

    final Map headers = new HashMap<>();

    // Use components to create the api request
    ApiRequest localRequest =
            new ApiRequest(apiClient.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .withPath(path)
                    .withHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.valueOf(method))
                    .withHeaders(headers)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withParameters(parameters);
    ...
```

As you can see i used:

```
final String path = "/test_rds_lambda/?name="+mName+"&class="+mClass;
```

This is the error i get from it:

```
{message=No method found matching route test_rds_lambda/%3Fname%3DYoME%26class%3DYoClass for http method POST.}
```

My Request URL path has

> ?,=

etc, but they are changed to HEX. i.e

> %3Fname%3D

How to prevent that from happening as it is working in "test api" in aws console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have solved the issue by putting data in JSONObject and then passing it into body parameter of cloud logic.

```
public void callCloudLogic() throws JSONException {
    // Create components of api request
    final String method = "POST";

    final String path = "/lambda_func";

    *--> JSONObject data =new JSONObject();
    *--> data.put("mCase","1");
    *--> final String body = data.toString();
    *--> final byte[] content = body.getBytes(StringUtils.UTF8);

    final Map parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("lang", "en_US");

    final Map headers = new HashMap<>();

    // Use components to create the api request
    ApiRequest localRequest =
            new ApiRequest(apiClient.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .withPath(path)
                    .withHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.valueOf(method))
                    .withHeaders(headers)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Post parameters should be sent in the body of the request.

Here is the method on the aws-sdk-android:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/apigateway/ApiRequest.java#L163